# how to use "libtext-dhcpleases-perl" debian package?

Tags: perl, dhcp

"libtext-dhcpleases-perl"  is one debian package available to parse dhcp lease files. I have installed it in ubuntu by using `apt-get install libtext-dhcpleases-perl`. Anybody is aware of how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `perldoc Text::DHCPLeases`, the same is also [available online](http://search.cpan.org/~cvicente/Text-DHCPLeases-0.9/lib/Text/DHCPLeases.pm):

```
use Text::DHCPLeases;

my $leases = Text::DHCPLeases->new("/etc/dhcpd.leases");

foreach my $obj ( $leases->get_objects ){
    print $obj->name;
    if ( $obj->binding_state eq 'active' ){
       ...
    }
}
```